# Rails - Why am I getting an undefined method `request` method within a work - Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've created a module:

```
module DomainSystem

  def set_db
    @domain = request.domain
    ...
  end
  ...

end
```

Which I've included in a Worker:

```
class InvoiceSchedulerWorker

    include Sidekiq::Worker
    include Sidetiq::Schedulable
    include DomainSystem

    recurrence { daily }

    def perform
      @var = set_db
      ...
    end
```

Now whenever I call this schedule worker I get an error:

```
    2015-09-29T10:04:57.108Z 7998 TID-ow95f5gng WARN: {"class"=>"InvoiceSchedulerWorker", "args"=>[], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"557fb942292b0d7e72043d74", "created_at"=>1443438228.0314932, "enqueued_at"=>1443521097.099235, "error_message"=>"undefined local variable or method `request' for #<InvoiceSchedulerWorker:0x007fc15a307500>", "error_class"=>"NameError", "failed_at"=>1443521097.103601, "retry_count"=>0}
    2015-09-29T10:04:57.108Z 7998 TID-ow95f5gng WARN: NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for #<InvoiceSchedulerWorker:0x007fc15a307500>
    2015-09-29T10:04:57.108Z 7998 TID-ow95f5gng WARN: /Library/WebServer/Documents/ruby/myjarvis/lib/domain_system.rb:50:in `set_db'
```

Why is that?

I thought the `request` variable was available throughout the whole Rails app...

Comment: Only controllers and views I think, in any case, no request is being made for a scheduled job is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekiq is not part of your Rails app. It's executed as a separate process so there is no way for Sidekiq to know details of your request.

Even worse, you should pass only "[simple](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple)" argument values to Sidekiq worker, while those arguments are stored as JSON string in Redis database.

So there is no way to share Rails state with Sidekiq, except passing all required parameters manually.

Comment: Now I got it. How can I pass an argument to a scheduled job (such as my example)? This particular job is not being called elsewhere but only through the scheduler...

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK you should probably put them in config then

Comment: But that's the tricky part though, this is a multi-domain app, so I can't have it hardcoded in a config file.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK where are you expecting to get the request from ? As far as I see, a job is launched, and you expect a request to be present there... If this job is launched within a scheduler, there logically cannot be a request, unless you "create" one.

Comment: @uno_ordinary ok, it seems I can't use Sidekiq for this particular task or I need to rethink how to assert which db to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sharded system with multiple databases and want to run a task across all databases then in your scheduled job you should create a separate job for each database:

```
class SomeScheduledWorker
  def perform
    each_database do |dbname|
      InvoiceSchedulerWorker.perform_async(dbname)
    end
  end
end
```

Scheduled jobs do not have arguments.  They can create other jobs with arguments though, as above.  Now your InvoiceSchedulerWorker job knows which database to use.